# How to fix this Run time error?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, runtime-error

I am trying to make a java program which will find and remove repetative characters in string. Like if user types "baloon", the output should be "balon". I used String variable for input and copied its content to Char array so that I can analyze each character. I get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Here is my code

```
class doubleKiller{

private String inputStr = " ";
private char[] catchStr = new char[inputStr.length()];
private String modifiedStr;

//Accessor method
public void getString(String inputStr)
{
    this.inputStr = inputStr;
}

public String killRepeater()
{

    //copying string data to char array
    this.inputStr.getChars(0 , this.inputStr.length() , catchStr , 0);

    //------------------

    for(int counter = 0 ; counter < this.inputStr.length() ; counter++)
    {
        if(catchStr[counter] != catchStr[counter - 1])
        {
            modifiedStr = modifiedStr + catchStr[counter];
        }
    }

    return modifiedStr;
}
```

}

Here is Output when killRepeater() is called.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: src.length=5 srcPos=0 dst.length=1 dstPos=0 length=4

at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
at java.lang.String.getChars(String.java:894)   
at doubleKiller.killRepeater(Main.java:23)
    at useThings.main(Main.java:49) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.aide.ui.build.java.RunJavaActivity$1.run(SourceFile:108) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:862)
```

Tell me my error...Thanks in advance

Comment: On the first iteration of your loop, `counter` is zero, so `catchStr[counter - 1]` is trying to get the element at index `-1`.

Comment: On top of what Joe Clay said, you may want to revise your condition to account for when your loop is starting so you won't go out of bounds.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing

```
private String inputStr = " "; 
private char[] catchStr = new char[inputStr.length()];
```

`inputStr.length()` returns `1`, that is, **the size from the string** " ", so, you have a **char array with size 1**.

When you do:

```
for(int counter = 0 ; counter < this.inputStr.length() ; counter++){
    if(catchStr[counter] != catchStr[counter - 1]){
```

With a `inputStr.length() > 1` you have an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Also, when run `catchStr[counter - 1])` for the first time, `counter-1` would generate `-1`, **which isn't a valid index**. Try running the `counter` from `1` to avoid this error.

Declare your array with a **fixed size**(e.g 200) or use an `ArrayList`. You could also put `catchStr = new char[inputStr.length()]` **after taking the input of the String.**

Answer (score 1):

Good thing that you asking about specific problem, but in case you interested how to make this simpler, there is regex magic

```
String in = "ballooooon";
String out = in.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1"); // balon
```

Which means

> find any symbol, save it to group 1, if next symbol, or symbols are equal to group 1, delete them and leave just one from the group.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing catchStr with inputStr.length().  But at this time inputStr = " ".  So catchStr has a length of 1.  When you later populate inputStr to a bigger value, you try and copy that into a char[] of length 1 and it doesn't fit.  Add `catchStr = new char[inputStr.length()];` right before you do the copy.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialise `catchStr` it will always have the value of 1, because `inputStr` is `" "` and therefore it's length is 1.

```
private String inputStr = " ";
private char[] catchStr = new char[inputStr.length()];
```

When you loop on `counter` in the method `killRepeater()` you will get an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` because the string you pass in `getString` is probably greater than 1.

---

Consider moving `new char[inputStr.length()]` into `getString`.

```
public void getString(String inputStr) {
    this.inputStr = inputStr;
    this.catchStr = new char[inputStr.length()];
}
```

And, setting the attribute `catchStr` to uninitialised.

```
private char[] catchStr;
```

---

The second issue is with your `for` loop. You start the `counter` at 0 and use `catchStr[counter - 1]` to look back on the previous character. This will not work when `counter = 0` because the index will evaluate to -1.

Consider starting your `counter` at 1, and continue to work on the method from there. You'll need to tweak it a little to get it output the desired string.

```
for (int counter = 1; counter < this.inputStr.length(); counter++) {
    if (catchStr[counter] != catchStr[counter - 1]) {
        modifiedStr = modifiedStr + catchStr[counter];
    }
}
```